# Get URL of image just sent

Tags: python, image, file, url, discord.py

## Problem

I want to retrieve the URL of the image I sent that has a `discord.file` in the parameters of `ctx.channel.send()`. However, I do not know how to get the sent image.

## Code

```
@bot.command()
async def testing(ctx, user: discord.Member):
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
endpoint = str(user.avatar_url)
async with session.get(str(endpoint)) as end:
    pfp = await end.read()
        with io.BytesIO(pfp) as file:
            msg = await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(file, filename=f"pfp.png")) 
            #i want image url of this discord.file
```

Answer (score 0):

### To get a message's attachments

In the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) it shows that `discord.Message` (the message object) has the attribute [attachments](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.attachments). This attribute gives a list of [`discord.Attachment`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment)s.

You can access an individual attachment via `message.attachments[i]` where `message` is the message object, and i is the index.

### To get the message link

To get the link of the attachment, [`discord.Attachment`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment) has the attribute [`url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Attachment.url). This gives a type string of the URL.

### In your example

```
@bot.command()
async def testing(ctx, user: discord.Member):
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
endpoint = str(user.avatar_url)
async with session.get(str(endpoint)) as end:
    pfp = await end.read()
        with io.BytesIO(pfp) as file:
            msg = await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(file, filename=f"pfp.png")) 
            msg_image_url = msg.attachments[0].url  # The URL of the image
```

### Problems that may occur

- You need to have the proper intents

> If Intents.message_content is not enabled this will always be an empty list unless the bot is mentioned or the message is a direct message.

- If the attachment is deleted, the URL will return none

> If the message this attachment was attached to is deleted, then this will 404.